# When function ended, about the local variable

Tags: javascript

I thought when a function ended,

all local variable, object in the function disappear in the memory

and :

```
var o1 = {A:100}    
var o2 = o1;
```

o2 object references same memory with o1.

therefore:

```
function Func() {
    var o1 = {A:100, b:200}
    return o1
}

var o2 = Func()

console.log(o2)
```

I think after Func return o1 object

Func function end and all local variable in Func function disappear

thus o2 references o1 but,

because o1 disappeared in memory

output of `console.log(o2)` is `"undefined"`

but still o2 can refer o1

how is it possible?

I wonder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript garbage collector will not deallocate the memory of a variable if another variable references it. Since `o2` still references the same memory as `o1`, that memory is not deallocated:

> An object is said to be "garbage", or collectible if there are zero references pointing to it.

see [MDN - Garbage Collector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#Reference-counting_garbage_collection)

Answer (score 0):

o2 does not reference o1 per se. Rather, it references the same object in memory.

In other words, it's not o2 pointing to o1 which points to the object in memory. Rather, both o2 and o1 directly point to the same object.